# Multiple select for CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am attempting to do a multiple select-delete for my CakePHP `Payment` Model.

I have a line in my view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('Payments.'.$payment['Payment']['id'], array('value' => $payment['Payment']['id'], 'hiddenField'=>false)); ?>
```

that creates checkboxes with the payment id as the value.  I have a method in my controller that gets called when I click a button on the view page.  This is the only code running within the method.

```
foreach ($this->request->data['Payments'] as $key => $value) {
    $this->Payment->delete($key);
}
```

For some reason, this does not appear to be working.  I get these errors

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: Payments [APP/Controller/PaymentsController.php, line 114]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Controller/PaymentsController.php, line 114]
```

which are both occurring because of the call to `$this->request->data`.

I did a bunch of research on cake and this appears to be the right syntax.
If anyone has any experience with this, it would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably need $this->request->data['Payment']['Payments'], if the model name is Payment

Answer (score 0):

Check $this->request->data['Payments'] array it should be in below format:

```
array('12'=>'12','87'=>'87');
```

if not then try $this->data['Payments']

```
foreach($this->request->data['Payments'] as $key => $value){
            $this->Payment->deleteAll(array('Payment.id' => $key), false);
            }
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to be receiving the data I am passing, as this array is empty for some reason.

Comment: maybe this is part of the problem.  as of now i have no ajax call code.

Comment: So you are posting a form? if yes then check $this->data, also $this->params